# Angular Controller Inheritance with $on function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-analytics, controller

what i need is following. I have a tracking that needs to be enabled for multiple services (fb pixel track, google analytic, kenshoo tracking, ...)
Now i created $broadcast for every event that i need to track, and controller for every service that we support.

So what i have is 
fbController and in it function that says

```
 $on("trggerTrack", function(){ //work track stuff});
```

And the problem that i have is i have a check before every event in all controllers that check in array if that event should be emited for that service (some clicks are not tracked by Kenshoo and are with GA). 
So i would like a parent controller that has

```
$on("triggerTrack", function(){
    if(!checkIftrack()) { return true;}
    track(); //Method that will be called in from subcontroller
});
```

Is that plausible??? Note: I need that $on("triggerTrack") to be called as many times as there are subcontrolers.

Comment: Do you not know what your subcontrollers are? Why not use `$emit` and send the event info up the inheritance chain instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a `service` for every tracking system that you use and attach the event on the `$rootScope` with `$rootScope.$on("triggerTrack", callback)`. Inside your controllers, you can use `$scope.$emit("triggerTrack", data)` to send a event upper in the scope chain, resulting in the `$rootScope`.